# Drill through RDLC Report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

I had created the Drill through (Textbox Property -> Action -> Go to report) RDLC Report and the steps given in below site,

`msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn154774.aspx`

But I am getting the following error while navigating the Report 1 to Report 2.

> A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'Tenant'

Screenshots

[image: Screen-shot 1]

[image: Screen-shot 2]

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but maybe it will be useful for someone else. When in the reportviewer there is a jump to other report (detail report) you need to add the DataSource for the detail report. You can do this easily by implementing the event method 'Drillthrough'. Go to the events of your reportViewer instance, create the method, and add a code like this:

```
private void reportViewer1_Drillthrough(object sender, DrillthroughEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource dataSrc = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
        dataSrc.Name = "DataSet1";
        dataSrc.Value = this.DataTable1BindingSource;

        LocalReport localReport = (LocalReport)e.Report;
        localReport.DataSources.Add(dataSrc);
    }
```

Please notice that the data source is being added to the report of the event parameter 'e'. **Not to the local report of the your reportViewer**

Answer (score 0):

As per the issue description,it seems that You have not initialized the **datasets of Report2** through **.Net code**.
The way you are initializing **datasets of reportt1**, at the same time and same way initialize the **datasets of reportt2 as** well.

Comment: I have initialized the datasets for Report2. I can able to run both Report1 and Report2 individually. While implementing the Drill-through Action, it showing the error mentioned above.

Comment: @Vinoth - Ok. Then it might be the case that at the click event, your report (report2) will be re-loaded/re-render in report viewer and that time associated datasets of report2 is getting reset to nothing.

Comment: It is possible to do this scenario without writing .Net Code? I mean configure everything on Report Page (Design Page) itself?

Comment: @Vinoth yes. you can. deploy your reports at report server and in report viewer configure it to server report instead of local report.